# Error in the simple shell script ( i.e.+ : unexpected `end of expression' )?

Tags: bash, ksh

```
find_totalusage()
{
    local totalusedsize=0
    for dirname in $dirnamelist
    do
        dirsize=$(find_dir_size "$dirname")
        totalusedsize=$(( $totalusedsize + $dirsize ))
    done
    echo $totalusedsize
}

size=$(find_totalusage)
```

Any one help me find the error ?

Comment: You have tagged your question both `bash` and `ksh` - which is it? Where are `dirnamelist` and `find_dir_size` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most likely explanation is that your `dirsize` variable is empty.

For example, in `bash`

```
$ foo=3; bar= ; echo $(( $foo + $bar ))
bash: 3 +  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+  ")
```

while in AT&T `ksh`

```
$ foo=3; bar= ; echo $(( $foo + $bar ))
ksh:  3 +  : more tokens expected
```

and in BSD `mksh`

```
$ foo=3; bar= ; echo $(( $foo + $bar ))
mksh:  3 +  : unexpected 'end of expression'
```

Note that all of these shells allow "bare" variable names like `(( foo + bar ))` in expressions, and this form may be preferable since it treats empty variables as zero values. From `man bash`:

```
   Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter  expansion  is  per‐
   formed before the expression is evaluated.  Within an expression, shell
   variables may also be referenced by name without  using  the  parameter
   expansion  syntax.  A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to
   0 when referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.
```

So for example

```
$ foo=3; bar=7 ; echo $(( foo + bar ))                                         
10

$ foo=3; bar= ; echo $(( foo + bar ))                                          
3
```

Comment: Yes you are correct.. Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score -1):

`man bash` documents the `for` command as:

```
for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done
```

`man ksh` says:

```
for name [in word ...]; do list; done
```

In both cases, you need a semicolon (`;`) to mark the end of the expression containing the words in `$dirlist`.

Comment: The newline is sufficient, surely?